# Abstract class + its static methods type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an abstract `BaseObject` class, which extends abstract `BaseEntity` class, and two classes that extend `BaseObject` - `User` and `Post`. Both `BaseEntity` and `BaseObject` have their own static methods.

Which type should have a parameter that would accept a constructor of `BaseObject`'s inheritors and would have access to all static methods?

Some example code:

```js
abstract class BaseEntity {
  static getById(id: number): BaseEntity {...}
}

abstract class BaseObject extends BaseEntity {
  static getBySlug(slug: string): BaseObject {...}
}

class User extends BaseObject {}
class Post extends BaseObject {}

class Interactor {
  doSomething(obj: ???) {
     obj.getById(3) // no error
     obj.getBySlug('foo') // no error
  }

  main() {
    this.doSomething(User) // no error
    this.doSomething(Post) // no error
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not make those method static if you plan to access them through the object. Static methods should be accessed by class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static methods are called by their Class name and not via an Object, since they belong to the `prototype` and have no access to the (correct) `this` context.

```
abstract class BaseEntity {
  static getById(id: number): BaseEntity {...}
}

abstract class BaseObject extends BaseEntity {
  static getBySlug(slug: string): BaseObject {...}
}

class User extends BaseObject {}
class Post extends BaseObject {}

class Interactor {
  doSomething(obj: new () => BaseObject) { // Since you want to call both method, let's assume "BaseObject" is more fitting
     // Since you are in a static context, you have no access to "obj" in the static method as long as you don't pass it (maybe a non-static function would be better?)
     BaseEntity.getById(3) // no error
     BaseObject.getBySlug('foo') // no error
  }

  main() {
    this.doSomething(User) // no error
    this.doSomething(Post) // no error
  }
}
```

Here a TypeScript [Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgUQDsIBLCATwQG8BYAKAQUmBNgQHMcJMyBJAEwAUxPgC4EBAK4BbEDigBKMdjD4ipCjXoMEUThKgFxOAO5JU6BDgAeEHAT4ZlqkuSoBfBAHpPCAFITIBAgAewQAB2QcXCCACxwkYKkw4kioABoEY3jdCH1DYCNTYgImAlh4iBjmSxs7BwQAMyhE2OIMFDQwOgY3Ol7aOlBIGHgzTqxcAHkQACscUetbe0dcQhcNbsYIZmJWDi4yAGVkCTYBMBO2MWHitkUJlWm50c1tHT0DQrGLRbqVx9m80QlA83j8AUQIXCkWilXisESyVSGSy71ynwKBBMCGKpXKsWqv2WjWaUla7XMXS0-X6dA6FgAqiooDUlvUnE8ge46ZSEAAFYKBInsqaAl602j0jA8IhyOAhFmvBB8YKHRKcGK3ATBWZKUXPCDyKheHyHYr4sjBCSZYBEIKhWDAZDIBAgYKVBBSDXBPgZSIQADkGE60niACIOWKIGGcRgpMFdI1SCQCGxNtowWayvFLdbgIniggCkwWAlZTYMrmEFUAG7xAihODlCxQsM6mYxwtwrY7Vheyo+osYZDBVNDhBVlUEAOIMLjUgIARSYBkWRF8SjgC0Jd2jQkZRIo8yVuQfFd8VkEFsUAA-PJ0wwnGt1AA6fbcfgCADMRrBDcsUDNFAD4PDgnLwG+nDcMcpwCAGDTBMEAa-j4-5yEBmwSgwy7FAIRpKgwlRtC+Kpqv2mqpgITJyChG4ARhWiEZqYAkaq6pEZRAqQLRaGAQmmF9EAA) to show that this compiles.